# C# Monitor behavior in case user quits application

Tags: c#, asp.net, synchronization, try-finally

I am using the following code for a critical section of a web page

```
if(Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj,60000))
{
  try{
       //write some things to a file
     }
  finally
  {
    Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
  }
}
```

Here, lockObj is a static member of the class. My question is, what happens if the user closes the web page or the browser while the critical section is being executed? Does lockObj remain locked for future page requests?

Comment: What is the page doing? A GET? A POST? Uploading a file?

Comment: in the critical section, it is writing to a log file on the server

Comment: Yes but what is the user doing? Just making a page request? Is anything being sent back to the user? I don't see how your server would even know if the user closed the page, as far as it cares, it would just send the response it was going to anyway.

Comment: why not using `lock() { ... }`? It is the same you have wrote yourself

Comment: In case this would matter, i assume Microsoft would have implemented the IDisposable interface, so that you can use the using keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing automatically occurs when the user closes a browser window or navigates to another page, if the request is still processing. This is why the [`HttpResponse.IsClientConnected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected.aspx) property exists - so your code can perform appropriate checks as and when you can do something useful.

If a timeout occurs on the server side, then the `finally` block should operate at around that time and the lock will be released. Whether it is *safe* for the lock to be released at this time is something only you can determine - the lock must have been put there for a reason, and if a timeout occurs, that may mean that the (shared, lock requiring state) isn't stable for whoever next acquires the lock.

But these are two very different sets of issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you somehow manage to kill the executing thread inside of

```
try {
  //write some things to a file
}
```

you might have some issues. But for all realistic cases with exceptions the code will function.

In effect, just avoid `Thread.Abort`.